# How do I join these two tables, showing results from the second table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query

I have two tables and I want the following result: if CID and CID2 are equal, print cpu about value of CID2.

Table A:

```
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| CID  | time                | step               | time_in_seconde |
+------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|    1 | 2017-07-27 06:26:50 | gege               |          10.229 |
|    2 | 2017-07-27 06:26:58 | rere               |          10.239 |
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 | gege               |          13.229 |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 | titi               |          12.823 |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 | fefe               |          12.667 |
```

Table B:

```
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
| CID2 | time                | cpu             |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 |          0.01   |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 |          0.05   |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 |          0.03   |
```

Result:

```
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
| CID2 | time                | cpu             |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
|    1 | 2017-07-27 06:26:50 |                 |
|    2 | 2017-07-27 06:26:58 |                 |
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 |          0.01   |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 |          0.05   |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 |          0.03   |
```

This query is what I've tried, but it doesn't work:

```
select A.cid, A.time, C.cpu 
  from A 
 INNER JOIN B on A.cid = B.CID2 
 where A.time ="2018-12-17 14:00:00";
```

I'm using mariadb.

Do you have any ideas?

I have also tried a query from @MikNiller, I don't want this, I want the same as below:

```
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
| CID2 | time                | cpu             |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+
|    1 | 2017-07-27 06:26:50 |       0.01      |
|    2 | 2017-07-27 06:26:58 |       0.05      |
|    3 | 2017-07-27 06:35:52 |       0.03      |
|    4 | 2017-07-27 06:36:56 |                 |
|    5 | 2017-07-27 06:55:04 |                 |
```

Comment: Could you confirm which "result set" is the one you want, and which is the incorrect one? From the information provided it seems that you need to "left join" A and B (so that you get all the results from A) and output B.cpu in your results. The SELECT query in your example can't produce the first table (as it is using inner join which will only give the rows that match by CID).

Comment: Btw, the fact that you have both "ID" and "time" (for what appears to be the same values) in both tables, points to a *possible* issue in the structure of how you are storing this data... but that's outside the scope of your question and may or may not be something you have any control over!

Comment: You show two different result sets. Which of the two do you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
 select A.cid, A.time, IF(A.cid = B.CID2,C.cpu,NULL) 
 from A 
 LEFT JOIN B on A.cid = B.CID2 
 where A.time ="2018-12-17 14:00:00";
```